# BoundsError: attempt to access 2×2 Matrix{VariableRef} at index [0, 0]

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I am trying to solve this IBM challenge (https://research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/challenges/March2021.html)
using jump in julia. but I get boundserror every time . I kinda feel my problem is regarding the size of X matrix, but I dont know how to fix it. can anyone help me ? I tried to use push! function, but I believe I couldnt use it properly.
here is my simplified code with 2x2 matrix:

````
p    = [0xBC 0xE6 ;
        0x72 0x57 ]
w = 128
m,n = size(p)    
mars = Model(GLPK.Optimizer)
@variable(mars, x[1:m,1:n], Bin)
Z = p.*x .- w
    
@objective(mars, Max, sum(Z) )
        
for i in 1:m
    for j in 1:n
        @constraint(mars, c1, x[i,j]- x[i-1,j-1]<=0 )
        @constraint(mars, c2, x[i,j]-x[i-1,j]<=0 )
        @constraint(mars, c3, x[i,j]-x[i-1,j+1]<=0 )
    end
end

optimize!(mars)
println("route: ", objective_value(mars))```
````

Answer (score 0):

When `i=1` and `j=1`

```
@constraint(mars, c1, x[i,j]- x[i-1,j-1]<=0 )
```

is

```
@constraint(mars, c1, x[1,1]- x[0,0]<=0 )
```

but `x[0,0]` isn't defined.

You need to modify your loops to exclude the boundaries.